# How to allow both types ref callback and MutableRefObject?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've trying to allow both types `(ref: any) => void Or MutableRefObject<any>`

```
 interface RowProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<React.ReactHTML> {
    componentRef: (ref: any) => void | React.MutableRefObject<any>;
    //...
}
```

**RowProps** interface has `componentRef` which has multiple type.

I expected to allow both types, but:

```
    let refFuncVer = React.useRef(null);
    let refObjectVer = React.useRef(null);

    // It is okay
    componentRef={(ref) => {refFuncVer.current = ref;}}


    // type error:
    componentRef={refObjectVer}
```

Why is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put parentheses around your function type definition:

```
componentRef: ((ref: any) => void) | React.MutableRefObject<any>;
```

The TypeScript compiler thinks you meant:

```
componentRef: (ref: any) => (void | React.MutableRefObject<any>);
```